# Why I am unable to see anything in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import About from './about';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Route path="/abou" component={About} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

about.js

```
import React from 'react'

const about = () => {
  return (
    <div>about</div>
  )
}

export default about
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-router",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Doubt???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

**I have installed react-router-dom as you can see in the package.json file but though it is compiling correctly, I am unable to see anything. What could be the error please let me know?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component Route should be a child of the component Routes and in Route component you have to use the property *element* to specify the component to render instead of the property *component*.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import About from './About';
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'; 


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I noticed that you have confusion between react-router v5 and v6 (you are using v6)
So for more information about react-router v6 visit the official react-router documentation website : https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6